# Fetch: reject promise and catch the error if status is not OK?

Tags: javascript, redux, fetch-api

Here's what I have going:

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';

function fetchVehicle(id) {
    return dispatch => {
        return dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_VEHICLE',
            payload: fetch(`http://swapi.co/api/vehicles/${id}/`)
                .then(status)
                .then(res => res.json())            
                .catch(error => {
                    throw(error);
                })
            });
    };
}

function status(res) {
    if (!res.ok) {
        return Promise.reject()
    }
    return res;
}
```

EDIT: The promise doesn't get rejected, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

I'm using this [fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) in Redux with [redux-promise-middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware).

Comment: You throw an exception in `catch` but do not `catch` it.

Comment: It *does* get to the `catch` (which catches all rejections in the whole chain it is attached to), but the `catch` callback doesn't handle anything - it only rethrows the error. Replace the `throw` with a `console.error` or so.

Comment: The browser freezes? That definitely shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm a bit new to this, the freeze was caused by something else. I think this is an issue for me because the [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) treats a 404 as a successful response. I'm having a bit of trouble rejecting the promise, once I figure that out it should be fine.

Comment: something more good github.com/github/fetch/issues/203#issuecomment-143347675

Comment: Anyone else here because the Angular httpClient rejects on 4xx and 5xx responses?

Answer (score 509, accepted):

[Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) promises only reject with a TypeError when a network error occurs. Since 4xx and 5xx responses aren't network errors, there's nothing to catch. You'll need to throw an error yourself to use `Promise#catch`.

A [fetch Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) conveniently supplies an [`ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) , which tells you whether the request succeeded. Something like this should do the trick:

```
fetch(url).then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  throw new Error('Something went wrong');
})
.then((responseJson) => {
  // Do something with the response
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: I did not find a property 'ok' instead I checked for response.status === 200.

Comment: Why can't I tell from my code why the TypeError was thrown?  In the console I see in one case it was "net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" but in another it was "(blocked:mixed-content)" and I don't want to respond the same to both.

Comment: will this solution stops getting errors in console such as 401 invalid request ?

Comment: How can we return custom responses when there's no network connection or when the server responded with e.g. a `503 Service Temp. Unavailable` if the result of a rejected promise is a `TypeError`?

Comment: How can I read a JSON in the catch? I send additional data from the BE that I need in the catch block

Comment: @LucasBustamante You can throw `JSON.stringify(response.json())` or `JSON.stringify(response.json(), null, 2)` for a prettier output.

Comment: Recently I can't catch the error that happens because of the network, I did exacly the same you wrote but still I get the predefined error `Failed to fetch` and it doesn't show the error message that I define inside of the then method after the first fetch method

Answer (score 78):

The following `login with username and password` example shows how to:

1. Check `response.ok`
2. `reject` if not OK, instead of throw an error
3. Further process any error hints from server, e.g. validation issues

```
login() {
  const url = "https://example.com/api/users/login";
  const headers = {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };
  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: this.username,
      password: this.password,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      // 1. check response.ok
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      return Promise.reject(response); // 2. reject instead of throw
    })
    .then((json) => {
      // all good, token is ready
      this.store.commit("token", json.access_token);
    })
    .catch((response) => {
      console.log(response.status, response.statusText);
      // 3. get error messages, if any
      response.json().then((json: any) => {
        console.log(json);
      })
    });
},
```

Comment: This worked for me! It seems that throw doesn't work like one might be used to in other languages. Simply returning Promise.reject() will pass all subsequent .thens and land in the next catch

Comment: Everywhere I find only approaches in which the pure error codes are written to the console. For a possible internationalization / representation of an error message for the users this is unsuitable. Unfortunately, I have also not yet found a 100% suitable solution.

Comment: So if the initial `fetch()` call actually throws an error, how can we differentiate that? Just a `typeof` check on the argument?

Answer (score 29):

Thanks for the help everyone, rejecting the promise in `.catch()` solved my issue:

```
export function fetchVehicle(id) {
    return dispatch => {
        return dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_VEHICLE',
            payload: fetch(`http://swapi.co/api/vehicles/${id}/`)
                .then(status)
                .then(res => res.json())    
                .catch(error => {
                    return Promise.reject()
                })
            });
    };
}


function status(res) {
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(res.statusText);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: You could also reject the Promise from your status function as so:
```function status(res) {
    if (!res.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(res.statusText);
    }
    return res;
}```

Or actually you could reject the promise with the message given by your endpoint.

Comment: Or actually you could reject the promise with the message given by your endpoint if you jsonfy that response and then return a Promise rejected with the properties that you choose from your jsonfied response.

Comment: That `.catch(error => {
                    return Promise.reject()
                })` seems rather pointless. Why suppress the useful `error` and reject with `undefined` instead?

Comment: @Bergi The reason why `return Promise.reject()` could be useful inside `catch` is that you can further chain the promise otherwise with a plain catch you would need to check for non empty arg in the `success handler`.

Comment: @Vivek Or you could equally just `throw undefined;`. What I'm complaining about was not the rejection, but ignoring the `error`. Probably the whole thing should be omitted though.

Comment: @Bergi Wouldn't `.catch(e=> { console.log(e); return Promise.reject(); })` make sense there for logging the error thrown in success handler and protecting the flow from landing into the next success handlers in case the `catch` is further chained.

Comment: @Vivek That might make more sense, but that's not what they did. Also using `undefined` instead of an error with a proper message is still a bad practice.

Comment: What if you want to return error set by the API in the body? res.statusText just gives you the generic http error messages.

Answer (score 29):

For me,
fny answers really got it all. since fetch is not throwing error, we need to throw/handle the error ourselves.
Posting my solution with async/await. I think it's more strait forward and readable

**Solution 1: Not throwing an error, handle the error ourselves**

```
  async _fetch(request) {
    const fetchResult = await fetch(request); //Making the req
    const result = await fetchResult.json(); // parsing the response

    if (fetchResult.ok) {
      return result; // return success object
    }


    const responseError = {
      type: 'Error',
      message: result.message || 'Something went wrong',
      data: result.data || '',
      code: result.code || '',
    };

    const error = new Error();
    error.info = responseError;

    return (error);
  }
```

Here if we getting an error, we are building an error object, plain JS object and returning it, the con is that we need to handle it outside.
How to use:

```
  const userSaved = await apiCall(data); // calling fetch
  if (userSaved instanceof Error) {
    debug.log('Failed saving user', userSaved); // handle error

    return;
  }
  debug.log('Success saving user', userSaved); // handle success
```

**Solution 2: Throwing an error, using try/catch**

```
async _fetch(request) {
    const fetchResult = await fetch(request);
    const result = await fetchResult.json();

    if (fetchResult.ok) {
      return result;
    }

    const responseError = {
      type: 'Error',
      message: result.message || 'Something went wrong',
      data: result.data || '',
      code: result.code || '',
    };

    let error = new Error();
    error = { ...error, ...responseError };
    throw (error);
  }
```

Here we are throwing and error that we created, since Error ctor approve only string, Im creating the plain Error js object, and the use will be:

```
  try {
    const userSaved = await apiCall(data); // calling fetch
    debug.log('Success saving user', userSaved); // handle success
  } catch (e) {
    debug.log('Failed saving user', userSaved); // handle error
  }
```

**Solution 3: Using customer error**

```
  async _fetch(request) {
    const fetchResult = await fetch(request);
    const result = await fetchResult.json();

    if (fetchResult.ok) {
      return result;
    }

    throw new ClassError(result.message, result.data, result.code);
  }
```

And:

```
class ClassError extends Error {

  constructor(message = 'Something went wrong', data = '', code = '') {
    super();
    this.message = message;
    this.data = data;
    this.code = code;
  }

}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Beware if `fetchResult.ok` is false, the response might not contain json data, in which case you'd get a different exception trying to call `fetchResult.json()`

Comment: Might be a possibility to check, if the fetchRestult content contains json. Maybe like this:
`const contentType = fetchResult.headers.get('content-type')
if (contentType && contentType.indexOf('application/json') !== -1) { const result = await fetchResult.json()}`

Answer (score 19):

### **2021 TypeScript Answer**

What I do is write a `fetch` wrapper that takes a generic and if the `response` is `ok` it will auto `.json()` and type assert the result, otherwise the wrapper throws the `response`

```js
export const fetcher = async <T>(input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit) => {
  const response = await fetch(input, init);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw response;
  }

  return response.json() as Promise<T>;
};
```

and then I'll catch errors and check if they are an `instanceof` `Response`. That way TypeScript knows that `error` has `Response` properties such as `status` `statusText` `body` `headers` etc. and I can apply a custom message for each `4xx` `5xx` status code.

```js
try {
  return await fetcher<LoginResponse>("http://localhost:8080/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email: "user@example.com", password: "passw0rd" }),
  });
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof Response) {
    switch (error.status) {
      case 401:
        throw new Error("Invalid login credentials");
      /* ... */
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unknown server error occured: ${error.statusText}`);
    }
  }
  throw new Error(`Something went wrong: ${error.message || error}`);
}
```

and if something like a network error occurs it can be caught outside of the `instanceof` `Response` check with a more generic message i.e.

```js
throw new Error(`Something went wrong: ${error.message || error}`);
```

Comment: Is it in any way possible to distinguish between 500 and 503 status codes? Often in these cases the variable `error` is not an instance of `Response`, so I have no further information about the source of the error (Server offline

Answer (score 8):

The answer by @fny (the accepted answer) didn't work for me. The `throw new Error()` wasn't getting picked up by the `.catch`. My solution was to wrap the `fetch` with a function that builds a new promise:

```
function my_fetch(url, args) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, args)
    .then((response) => {
      response.text().then((body) => { 
        if (response.ok) {
          resolve(body) 
        } else {
          reject(body) 
        }
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => { reject(error) })
  })
}
```

Now every error and non-ok return will be picked up by the `.catch` method:

```
my_fetch(url, args)
.then((response) => {
  // Do something with the response
})
.catch((error) => {
  // Do something with the error
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Another (shorter) version that resonates with most answers:

```
fetch(url)

.then(response => response.ok
    ? response.json()
    : Promise.reject(response)) //throw if not 200-OK

.then(json => doStuff(json)) //all good

.catch(response => handleError(response)) //handle errors
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}
fetch("https://example.com/api/users")
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => console.log("ok") )
    .catch(error => console.log(error) );
```

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't satisfied with any of the suggested solutions, so I played a bit with [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to find a way to handle both success responses and error responses.

Plan was to get `{status: XXX, message: 'a message'}` format as a result in both cases.

Note: Success response can contain an empty body. In that case we fallback and use `Response.status` and `Response.statusText` to populate resulting response object.

```
fetch(url)
  .then(handleResponse)
  .then((responseJson) => {
    // Do something with the response
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });

export const handleResponse = (res) => {
  if (!res.ok) {
    return res
      .text()
      .then(result => JSON.parse(result))
      .then(result => Promise.reject({ status: result.status, message: result.message }));
  }
  return res
    .json()
    .then(result => Promise.resolve(result))
    .catch(() => Promise.resolve({ status: res.status, message: res.statusText }));
};
```

Comment: What's the purpose of result => Promise.resolve(result). Either result is a Promise or not, but then would handle it either way, wrapping it in a Promise just creates an extra layer that will immediately get unwrapped, no?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the status of the response object in particular by using its -ok property that indicates a successfull response (status from 200 - 299) per boolean.

```
$promise.then( function successCallback(response) {  
  console.log(response);
  if (response.ok) { ... }
});
```

Comment: Not good enough, 201 (Resource Created) is also a valid response, in fact anything in the range 200-299 is not a client error.

Comment: Use [`response.ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok): The `ok` read-only property of the `Response` interface contains a Boolean stating whether the response was successful (status in the range 200-299) or not.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps for me **throw Error** is not working

```
function handleErrors(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject({
          status: response.status,
          statusText: response.statusText,
        });
      }, 0);
    });
  }
  return response.json();
}

function clickHandler(event) {
  const textInput = input.value;
  let output;
  fetch(`${URL}${encodeURI(textInput)}`)
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then((json) => {
      output = json.contents.translated;
      console.log(output);
      outputDiv.innerHTML = "<p>" + output + "</p>";
    })
    .catch((error) => alert(error.statusText));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(url, options)
  .then (
    async (response) => {
      const json = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log(json)
      }
      else {
        console.log(json)
      }
    }
  )
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

By inspiration from the [marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38236296/6877799) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62774613/6877799) and also my thoughts on using `async/await` and have a more legible and more synchronous-like code, I prefer to answer the question post like the following:

```js
const _call = async <T = any>(
  method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE',
  url: string,
  data?: any
): Promise<T> => {

  try {
    const fetchResult = await fetch(url, {
      method,
      ...(data ? { body: JSON.stringify(data) } : {}),
    });
    const result = await fetchResult.json();

    if (!fetchResult.ok) {
       // Here you can throw your error type as you wish
       throw result;
    }

    return result;

  } catch (e) {

    // Sentry.captureException(e);
    throw e;
  }
};
```

**HINT**: Obviously, this `_call` wrapper function upon the Fetch API needs more things like `headers` or `params` handling. This answer is a short term of my complete version and I reduced many checks and handlers to create a simple and legible code for here.

Answer (score 0):

### As fetch only catch the network errors in the catch block, its better to use Axios which catch both the network errors and HTTP errors in catch block.

As simple as this:

```
axios.get(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
```

For documentation: https://axios-http.com/docs/intro