# React API Handle Error in Fetch Call : TypeError-Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a weather app, which is working fine for valid city names but doesn't work for wrong city names.

I have built two modules, the first one is App.js and second one is Form.js which is to pass the city name entered by the user to the App.js

App.js is:-

```js
import React from 'react';
import Form from './form.js';
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    weather:{
    temp:"",
    type:"",
    city:"",
    country:"",
    wind:"",
    humidity:""} ,
    requestSuccessfull:true
  }

  updateWeatherDetails = (area) =>{
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${area}&units=metric&APPID=b66ecf3c7e717c4eb45abd13e53ba0ac`,{mode:'cors'})
    .then((response)=>{
      return (response.json());
    })
    .then((response) =>{
      this.setState((prevState) =>({
        weather : { 
            temp:response.main.temp,
            type:response.weather[0].description,
            city:response.name,
            country:response.sys.country,
            wind:response.wind.speed,
            humidity:response.main.humidity,
        }
      }))
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
    this.setState({
    requestSuccessfull:false
   })
    console.log("error occured")

  })
}
  render(){

    if (this.state.requestSuccessfull){
      return(
      //display the weather details
      )

    }
    else{
      return(
        //display wrong city name entered by user
      )
    }
    }


}


export default App;
```

I don't understand why my catch function is not running. How else should I handle a bad API call? 
On submitting wrong city name is am getting an error as:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined
  22 | .then((response) =>{
  23 |   this.setState((prevState) =>({
  24 |     weather : { 
> 25 |         temp:response.main.temp,
     | ^  26 |         type:response.weather[0].description,
  27 |         city:response.name,
  28 |         country:response.sys.country,
```

Also one silly doubt. Shouldn't the error on API call should be ignored, since I attached the catch function to handle any error?

Comment: What is the HTTP status code you're getting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235715/fetch-reject-promise-and-catch-the-error-if-status-is-not-ok

Comment: @Emil I'm getting response code as 404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MDN

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status
>   even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve
>   normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on
>   network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

The solution is to check the status code and throw an error when necessary.

```
 fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${area}&units=metric&APPID=b66ecf3c7e717c4eb45abd13e53ba0ac`,{mode:'cors'})
    .then((response)=>{
        if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error("Not 200 response")
       } else return (response.json());
    }).then(do stuff).catch(error => { handle error })
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked. I wonder how do you guys come to solution of problems like these? Did you know this already while studying fetch function? If not how did you search for it?

Comment: I had this issue too when I was learning APIs. You might like axios package since it checks for HTTP codes automatically and throws an error for you. Also, google is your best friend, that's what I did to answer your question.

Comment: okay, I saw axios somewhere in the internet will read about it now. Thanks again though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can accomplish something like this.. I believe it is easier to understand using async/await versus a promise. It is easier to keep track of what is happening.

*The example should be self explanatory, but please let me know if you have any questions. I am more than happy to help!*

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    weather: {
      temp: "",
      type: "",
      city: "",
      country: "",
      wind: "",
      humidity: ""
    },
    location: "",
    area: "",
    error: "",
    requestSuccessfull: ""
  };

  updateWeatherDetails = async event => {
    try {
      let area = this.state.location;
      let fetchUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${area}&units=metric&APPID=b66ecf3c7e717c4eb45abd13e53ba0ac`;
      let fetchOptions = { mode: "cors" };

      let response = await fetch(fetchUrl, fetchOptions);
      let weatherData = await response.json();

      let newstate = {
        weather: {
          temp: weatherData.main.temp,
          type: weatherData.weather[0].description,
          city: weatherData.name,
          country: weatherData.sys.country,
          wind: weatherData.wind.speed,
          humidity: weatherData.main.humidity
        },
        location: "",
        requestSuccessfull: true
      };

      this.setState(newstate);
      
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        requestSuccessfull: false,
        error: err,
        area: prevState.location,
        location: ""
      }));
    }
  };

  handleLocationChange = event => {
    this.setState({ location: event.target.value })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Area: {this.state.location}</p>
        <p style={{marginBottom:'0px'}}><small>Type a location to get weather</small></p>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.location} onChange={this.handleLocationChange} />
        <button onClick={this.updateWeatherDetails}>
          Get Weather
        </button>
        {this.state.requestSuccessfull === true ? (
          <div>
            SUCCESS <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.weather, null, 2)}</pre>
          </div>
        ) : this.state.requestSuccessfull === false ? (
          <div>
            ERROR GETTING DATA FOR '{this.state.area}' ENCOUNTERED ERROR: '{
              this.state.error && this.state.error.message
            }'
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I got the solution but async/await is looking lot cleaner and understandable to me, I will implement this. So await catch errors with 4xx and 5xx ? unlike promises?

Comment: Correct - if you enter an invalid location in the text box and click 'Get Weather' it will return a 404, which gets picked up in the `catch` block. You can verify that by browsing to this URL in your browser (you'll see the 404) http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=I%20DO%20NOT%20EXIST&units=metric&APPID=b66ecf3c7e717c4eb45abd13e53ba0ac - or enter `I DO NOT EXIST` in the location search box. Please make sure to mark my answer as accepted if it helped out! Cheers!!