# How to catch the error when making fetch api request?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fetch-api

I am sending request with fetch api and make action according to the result is correct or it includes error.

my service code:

```
LoginUser(user: User) {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
    });
  }
```

and my `then-catch` code which calls the above one is:

```
async loginUser() {
  let response = await this._service.LoginUser(this.user)
  .then(response => {return response.json()})
  .then(response => {this._router.navigate(['/mainpage'])})
  .catch(error => {alert(error)});
 }
```

Whether the response is coming with *code 500 Internal Server Error* still it is redirecting to `/mainpage` and does not recognise the error. How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Why fetch instead of Angular's HttpClient?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would use fetch instead of the Angular Http client?

Comment: the "boss" wanted me to use only fetch api, not jquery or others etc.

Comment: Is this not an Angular app..? It has a very good http client build in..?

Comment: Yes bro i know :(, but when the boss wants it, thats it unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch: reject promise and catch the error if status is not OK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235715/fetch-reject-promise-and-catch-the-error-if-status-is-not-ok)

Comment: Why would you even mention jQuery? Use Angular. It's supposed to be an Angular project, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using async await you shouldnt have to chain on .thens like you are resolving a promise.

I adjusted your code and wrapped it in a try/catch, the try/catch error will handle an error from a non response however you will need to check your server response for errors itself

```
async loginUser() {

    try {
        let response = await this._service.LoginUser(this.user)

        // Check your response for error this may not be response.error
        if (response.error) {
            // Handle error
            alert(error)
        } else {
            // Navigate on success
            this._router.navigate(['/mainpage'])
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

When a `fetch` request comes back with an error code from the server, the `catch` of the promise is not executed, the `then` is. The `catch` is only executed if there is a network failure. See [the fetch docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

What you need to do is, inside your `then`, check `response.ok`. If `response.ok == false`, then the request returned an error. You can find info about this error in `response.status` and `response.statusText`.