# React query mutation: getting the response from the server with onError callback when the API call fails

Tags: reactjs, mutation, react-query

I am working on a React JS project. In my project, I am using React query, https://react-query.tanstack.com/docs/guides/mutations. I am using mutation to make the post request to the server. But I am trying the get the response returns from the server when the API call fails with the onError call back.

This is my code.

```
let [ createItem ] = useMutation(payload => createItem(payload), {
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      // here I am trying to get the response. In axios, we can do something like error.data.server_error_code
    },
    onMutate: () => {
      
    }
  })
```

As you can see in the comment, I am trying to read a field returned from the server within the onError callback. How can I do that?

Comment: I would guess there's an issue with your `createItem` function and/or your redefinition of `createItem` in your array destructuring.

Comment: Well, how can I get  the response back within the onError callback?

Answer (score 13):

```js
let [ createItem ] = useMutation(payload => createItem(payload), {
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
    },
    onMutate: () => {
      
    }
})
```

It's not entirely clear when just doing `console.log(error)` inside `onError`, but `error.response` should be available.

Comment: `error.response` is not set for me. Cab you provide a link to documentation to support your solution?

Comment: @G.Shand `response` is populated in this case by Axios probably (`AxiosError<T>`) So you'd need to match the error format your fetch method or library is returning.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I capture the error message in the React app with react-query. For example, this is the payload my API sends back for the error

```
{ 
 statusCode: ERROR_CODE, 
 description: "YOUR_ERROR_MESSAGE" 
}
```

I am using axios for fetching API data, and I am using Typescript, so I would need to cast my error first to an instance of AxiosError class before extracting the message

```
onError: (error) => {
        if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
          console.error(error.response?.data.description)
        } else {
          console.error('GENERIC_ERROR_MESSAGE')
        }
      }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It should work as it is. Make sure that your HTTP client (probably, Axios) is configured to throw an error. For example:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useMutation } from 'react-query'
import { BASE_URL } from 'constants/api'

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
})

const request = (options) => {
  const onSuccess = (response) => response
  const onError = (error) => {
    // Throwing an error here
    throw error
  }
  return client(options).then(onSuccess).catch(onError)
}

const { mutate } = useMutation(
  async (data) =>
    await request({
      url: '/someUrl',
      method: 'post',
      data
    }),
    { onError: (e) => console.log(e) }
  )
```

And of course, it's better to store your Axios settings within a separate file, and then just import the 'request' variable where mutations are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `fetch`, you have to know that fetch does not throw any error unless is a network problem (as read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235715/fetch-reject-promise-and-catch-the-error-if-status-is-not-ok))

My solution was just to change to `axios` (which throws error when 400 or 500), but if you still need to use fetch, you need to find a way to make it throw errors instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with NOT having an `error.response` in the callback depends on how the API is failing. If you look at the react-query documentation it shows that most HTTP libs like axios will throw if there is a non 2xx response. However it's up to the underlying API function how it handles that.

For example axios https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors will return the response object if there is a response from the server. They will return the request if the call has timed out and return just a message if the previous two don't fit the error

```
 axios.get('/user/12345')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
  });
```

However, if you're using the Fetch API you have handle this yourself. Taken straight from react-query's docs: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-functions#usage-with-fetch-and-other-clients-that-do-not-throw-by-default

```
useQuery(['todos', todoId], async () => {
   const response = await fetch('/todos/' + todoId)
   if (!response.ok) {
     throw new Error('Network response was not ok')
   }
   return response.json()
 })
```