# Access to server-side validation errors in react-query mutation

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, xmlhttprequest, react-query

I have a basic API built in Laravel and a React app that is running alongside it. I'm making a PUT request to update some data via React Query, which works fine and the data goes through. I was looking to extend it to handle server-side validation errors (essentially calling Formik's `setErrors` on them). Laravel back-end responds with a 422 error, as expected, and I can see JSON with the field errors in the Network tab. However, trying to get hold of the error object in `react-query` mutation's callback only gives me text content:

```
VM3965 update-form.tsx:61 Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js?770c:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js?8768:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js?1a5c:66:1)
```

I sort of expected to be able to get hold of the `error` object containing the JSON with validation errors here. Probably missing something obvious.

Here's what the mutation hook looks like:

```
export const useUpdateClient = (id: string) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  return useMutation(
    (newClient: Client) => axios.put(`/api/clients/${id}`, newClient),
    {
      onSuccess: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(['clients']),
    },
  )
}
```

and this how I call it from the component:

```
const updateClient = useUpdateClient(id)
const handleSubmit = (
      values: Client,
      { setErrors }: FormikHelpers<Client>,
    ) => {
      updateClient.mutate(values, {
        onSuccess: () => {
          onClose(),
          toast({
            title: 'Client updated',
            status: 'success',
          })
        },
        onError: error => console.log(error), // <<< this only prints text
      })
    }
```

Comment: The answer was essentially following advice from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65096547/4268481 and other similar questions