# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'orgao') - WIX Web app w/ API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, velo

I'm making a web app using Wix and the API data won't display because of this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'orgao'). "Orgao" is one type of data the API provides. Here's the code:

FRONT-END

```
import {getCryptoCurrencyInfo} from 'backend/serviceModule';

$w.onReady(function () {
    // Write your JavaScript here

});

export function button1_click(event, $w) {
        getCryptoCurrencyInfo($w('#currencyInput').value)
        .then(currencyInfo => {
            $w('#result').text = "Orgao: " + currencyInfo[0].orgao + "\n" 
                                    + "Evento: " + currencyInfo[0].evento + "\n"
        });
}
```

BACK-END serviceModule.jsw

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';

export function getCryptoCurrencyInfo(month) {

    const url = 'https://transparencia.tce.sp.gov.br/api/json/despesas/2018/1';
    console.log("Url: " + url);

    return fetch(url, {method: 'get'})
        .then(response => response.json())

}
```

By the way, the names are a mix between a tutorial and my project, so don't get caught up on variables' names context. And the API doesn't require a token.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: what do you get when you log `currencyInfo` to the console? can you provide a sample?

Comment: The URL you're using responds with a 404 status and body `{"message":""}` which is not an array. You should handle non-successful responses. See [Fetch: reject promise and catch the error if status is not OK?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38236296/283366)

Comment: @yochanansheinberger Good one, it says: ```ReferenceError: currencyInfo is not defined```. Maybe ```currencyInfo``` it has something to do with the API of the tutorial I used, which is not available anymore. Any ideas on how to replace it?

Comment: @Phil My comment earlier didn't go up. Thank you for your comment, I was actually playing with changing the url and left it incomplete! It works now, so it was a simple mistake. Thank you again.