# Is there a way to handle wrong user input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fetch-api

I am working on a project in `React.js` with this API `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/`.

I want to be able to handle the error, when the user inputs a dog breed that does not exists such as **International space station**.

I need your help on error handling.

**Problem with the current code** It thows an error `imagesOfABreed is not a function`

Here is a look at my code.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // get the images of the breed that is choosen
    const loadByBreed = async (value: string) => {
      
    if(!value) {
      setImagesOfABreed([]);
      return;
    }
      
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${value}/images`)
        const data = await response.json()

        if (data?.status == "error") {
          setFetchError("breed not found")
          console.log(fetchError);
          setImagesOfABreed([])
          return
        }

        console.log(data)
        setImagesOfABreed(data.message)
      } catch (error) {
        const err = error as Error
        console.log(err.message)
      }
    }

    loadByBreed(debouncedQuery);

  }, [debouncedQuery])


return (

{fetchError && <p>{fetchError}</p>}

          { imagesOfABreed?.length ? imagesOfABreed.map((data) => {
            return (
              <Card key={data} img={data} />
            )
          }) : <p>Nothing</p>}


)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: *"I need your help on error handling."* - Please be more specific, see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  *"It thows an error imagesOfABreed is not a function"* - Nothing in the code shown attempts to invoke `imagesOfABreed` as a function.  Which specific operation is producing this error?

Comment: @Konrad It throws an error saying `imagesOfABreed is not a function` This is because user enters a name of a breed that does not exist such as **Hamburger**

Comment: @neil it would mean that you try to call `imagesOfABreed` as a function like: `imagesOfABreed()` but there is not code like this in the question

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can actually do is first call and store all possible dog breeds locally, and then check if the user input is in that array. If not, don't send the request.

Make sure to check if the api has something like a get all breeds or something like that. The rest should be easy to implement!

Let me know if you have any answers!

Comment: Hi @Noubar Please can you give a code example. Please

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the value type of `imagesOfABreed` and if it is an array then render the Card component through map. This is a safety check.

Change your code to this:

`debouncedQuery &&  Array.isArray(imagesOfABreed) && imagesOfABreed?.length ? ...`

**Edit:**
If you want to handle the errors if dog breed is not a valid one, user input is empty etc, then you will have to handle it individually. Replace `setFetchError("breed not found")` with  this:

```
if(data.message.startsWith('Breed not found')){
    setFetchError("breed not found");
}else if(data.message.startsWith('No route found')){
    setFetchError("breed name cannot be empty");
} else {
    setFetchError(data.message);
}
```

Comment: It did not work. Do not be offended, please.

Did you understand my question

Comment: I get an error `data.message.startsWith is not a function`

Comment: Can you post the entire try-catch block here. That would help understand why the error is being thrown.